# Representing C# TimeSpan in Bond

Tags: c#, bond

Is there an equivalent of C#'s [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) in the Bond type system? If not, how can I interoperate between `TimeSpan` and a field in a Bond struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no builtin type for C#'s `TimeSpan`, but you can use [custom type mapping](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#custom-type-mappings) to achieve the same result. See this official [example for DateTime](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/date_time).

Comment: I'd recommend using an `int64` field in the Bond struct to store the `TimeSpan.Ticks` value, which you'd then use in the converters.