# What are the available datatypes in C# bond?

Tags: c#, database, database-design, object-storage, bond

I'm wondering what is the best way to represent a table that should contain those fields in C# bond format?

- string FirstName
- string LastName
- string Email
- bool Registered
- DateTime DateJoined
- char Gender
- List<string> Favorites
- string City
- string State
- unit16 Zip
- string Country
- List<string> FrequentPagesURLs

And I want to have something similar to that format

```
namespace MyProject
{
    struct Key
    {
        0: required string Email;
    }

    struct Value
    {
        0: required string FirstName; 
        1: optional char Gender;
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to represent `char`, `DateTime`, and `List<string>` in C# bond format to use them in creating table in Object store.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation for Bond, there are the following types:

> Basic type: bool, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, int8, int16, int32, int64, float, double, string, wstring.
>
> Container: blob, list, vector, set, map, nullable.
>
> User-defined type: enum, struct or bonded where T is a struct.

However, the documentation also explains how to generate the DateTime, char, etc. if you are using bond to generate C# code. That is to use the following in your CLI command:

> gbc c# --using="DateTime=System.DateTime" date_time.bond

The using parameter is where you put type aliases, such as "char=System.Char;DateTime=System.DateTime".

I don't know if this adequately helps you, please let me know if you need anything else.

Sources:

https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/compiler.html

https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html

Comment: I got very confused in the part for generating DateTime, char, and so on.
I'm not sure how to write this in the schema file in the format I mentioned above.
It will be so great if you can provide example given the table that I need to create.

Comment: There's an existing question about [how to represent `TimeSpan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492730/implementing-an-equivalent-of-c-sharp-timespan-in-microsoft-bond), which points to an [example about `DateTime`](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/date_time).

Answer (score 2):

I would model the gender field as an enum, as this is more explicit than a char; the DateTime field as a `uint64`, but use [a type converter](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#converter) to turn this into [a DateTime struct in C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/date_time); and the `List<string>` field as a `vector<string>`:

```
namespace MyProject;

using DateTime=uint64;

enum Gender
{
    Unspecified;
    ...
}

struct Favorite { ... }
struct FrequentPagesURL { ... }

struct SomeType
{
    ...
    7: DateTime DateJoined;
    8: Gender Gender = Unspecified;
    9: vector<Favorite> Favorites;
    ...
    17: vector<FrequentPagesURL> FrequentPagesURLs;
    ...
}
```

You may want to consider modeling the DateJoined field as a `string`/`blob` and using a type converter to turn it into a [DateTimeOffset struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#, [depending on your needs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime).